# Does the propagation direction of a beam of light change after going through a wire grid polarizer?

Tags: optics, polarization

My intuition says no, since my understanding is the transmitting component behaves as if the polarizer is just a dielectric, but I don't know if there are any subtleties I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

If the polarizer sheet is perpendicular to the beam's direction, it won't change it. (As you said, your explanation is correct)